# How can I handle POST requests using Python?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I currently am working on a translator micro-service. Basically, I am using Google's Translation API to translate some text. This requires two variables, the language to translate to, and the text to be translated.
I want to be able to have someone send me a request to translate their text, but I have no idea how to get their information from them, nor do I know how to send the translated text back to them. I have look into the requests library, but I'm not sure where to begin.
Thanks!

Here is what I have currently:

```
import requests

def translate_text(target, text):
    import six
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

    translate_client = translate.Client()

    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")

    result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target)

    print(u"Text: {}".format(result["input"]))
    print(u"Translation: {}".format(result["translatedText"]))
    print(u"Detected source language: {}".format(result["detectedSourceLanguage"]))


translate_text("fr", "Hello, World!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Requests is mostly for sending requests AFAIK, but it might work. I think it's probably easier to use just a plain old webserver for something like this.

[Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) is probably the easiest way. It's an entire webserver, but you can define a route that they can then send a post request to. [This guide is handy](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/) for explaining this. You could just have the route take in a post request, do the text processing and then redirect to another webpage with the translated content and display it in HTML (assuming this is a web-based and not CLI application).

Alternatively there are other HTTP server systems you can use, or just [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html).